# WebRTC in android browsers

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am trying to record from the microphone using HTML5 in Chrome for Android. My code works fine on desktop browsers.

```
audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
```

is my code. But i get a "Undefined AudioContext" error.

Answer (score 0):

Without being sure about this, the error you get seems to complain on the class you are trying to instantiate.

Maybe what you are trying to do is

```
audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;
var audio = new audioContext();
```

Not sure about this, though.

Comment: This was a browser compatibility issue. It works fine. Now i'm having issues with converting the sample rate. Have you got any ideas about it?

Comment: Sorry, actually no idea. Maybe you should open a new question.